# Purchase Java with Arrays

Tags: java

I'm Raymond, computer programming student. I have problem about arrays. Are instructor ask us to do a program that goes like this.

in this codes below. i want to display the same item code i entered. but the problem is that once i answered yes and input again number, the only thing that display is the last number or code i enter.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class _TindahanArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ans, i = "";
        int x;

        do {

            System.out.print("Item code:");
            i += a.next();

            System.out.print("\nAnother item? [y/n]:");
            ans = a.next();

        } while (ans.equals("y"));

        String[] code = new String[2];

        for (x = 0; x < 1; x++) {

            code[x] = i;

            System.out.print(code[x]);

            code[x] = "\n";
            System.out.print(code[x]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Home work question. [see](http://stackoverflow.com/about) ask specific question, where do you stuck? I didn't down vote.

Comment: @Aniket:  I'd love to know why that matters...

Comment: Do you have any code that we could go off of?  Are you getting any error conditions when you run your program?

Comment: my first main problem is dealing with arrays that are not fix.

Comment: @Raymond Please show your codes?

Comment: can you please change your question text to be a question specifically about something you want to do with those arrays, then? arrays are simply fixed length. That's how they work. Either preallocate "enough room", or use an ArrayList or similar variable-length container. If you are only allowed arrays, you can create a new array that is length=oldarray.length+1, and then use the `System.arraycopy` function to move all your data from the old to the new array, with 1 extra free spot.

Comment: Try to solve it yourself first. Post code snippet which you tried. Friend we are not hear to spoon feed you.

Comment: [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) [array example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm)

Comment: @chait i understand. I'm just confused how will i use the array thing.

Comment: @Aniket. yah right, it's like a home work question. but at the same, it's the final machine problem we must finished this semester.

Comment: @Raymond: have you visited URLs that I have posted.

Comment: @gjman2 that's my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you shown some efforts, I just want to update your code.
Your code is fine for only printing two item codes.

Use collection [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to store the item codes. I am using String array list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ans;
    ArrayList<String> itemCodeList = new ArrayList<String>();  //create array list      

    do{

       System.out.print("Item code:");
       itemCodeList.add(a.next());  //add item code into array list

       System.out.print("\nAnother item? [y/n]:");
       ans = a.next();

    }while(ans.equals("y"));

    for (String code : itemCodeList) 
    {
        System.out.println(code);           
    }
   }
 }
```

- [ArrayList example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm)

Comment: So sir based on what you did. The output will looks like if enter for example 5 codes. it will be automatically saved. and display at the same time?

Comment: Yes. That's what you did in question. You are creating String array only with two elements. `String[] code = new String[2];` I have just used array list.

Comment: which means that the elements of my array will not be fixed? using the array list?

Comment: Wrong. ArrayList grows dynamically while arrays don't. Just read [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) [array example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm) and link in answer.

Comment: can an array list be possible in integers?

Comment: Yes.Array list can be [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) it is possible but with [Wrapper classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class)

Comment: Don't worry sir. I will read all the lessons you recommended.

Comment: I also need that sir because we must save the details of a specific item. like codes,name,quantity,price.

Comment: and eventually we can also buy that item.

Comment: by the way sir. thank you for the help. my mind is now clear about arrays. and thank you also for the recommended lessons. till next time.

Comment: to clarify. arrays are used as database? like in visual basic?

Comment: No. In any programming language both are different. Array in java and database both are different things. I don't know visual basic. My suggestion is you must read basic java book. If you have more doubts you can post new question. Thanks.

Comment: our instructor does'nt want array list